# How to use localization in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to use the localization in `ASP.NET`, I actually followed the Microsoft Documentation but I'm pretty confused right now.

This is what I did so far:

Inside the `Configure` method I added the following code (at the top of all):

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
   new CultureInfo("it-IT"),
   new CultureInfo("en-EN")
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
   DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it"),
   SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
   SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

so essentially I declared two supported languages, and set the italian to default.

Then inside the `ConfigureServices` I specified the `ResourcesPath`:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

This is actually the folder content:

[image]

I setted for both `.resx` file the access modificator to `public`, and then inside the `_ViewImports.cshtml` I added this:

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

The problem is that when I type `@Resources` inside a `View` I get:

> 'Resources' is not accessible due to the level of security

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on this? You should inject a `IViewLocalizer` to access your resources.

Comment: @poke and for access to `@Resources` instead? I find more useful access by property rather than an index

Comment: There is no such thing in ASP.NET Core. In order to use the static `Resources` class, there would have to be a code generation step which does not exist here. Also, it would be static, and ASP.NET Core generally avoids statics completely.

Comment: Have you tried using en-GB/en-US over the culture en-EN. In your controller action that executes before loading the StringLocalizer<T>, what is this value set to? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (Can you print it out to the debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the localization strings for controller in the view, you could do it that way:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localazier
```

After that `@localazier["YourKey"]`

I advise you to create empty class in your project for an example `SharedResources` and create specific resx file for it and after that just use it everywhere with `@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localazier`

Additionally a possible problem is your default culture. Asp.net core looks for the culture into one of this 3 places:

```
QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
CookieRequestCultureProvider
AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider
```

and only if the culture is empty for any of them it will take your default culture. So you should turn off `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` as possibility, because a lot of user could have defined it in their browser and it is possible to be different from IT.

This is the way to take it only from query string or cookie, so I advise you to implement it that way.

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
});
```

Comment: I did all the steps you suggested and when I start the software I see "Login" where I added this: `@Localizer["Login"]`, this is strange because the value of italian culture of the file `AccountController.it-IT.resx` is `Accedi`, what is wrong? Seems that the software cannot locate the culture and display the index `Login`

Comment: @Charanoglu put it in debug and see if the localization string is found. There is property which says that. Also you need to define your default culture as DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it-IT"). The property which you need to check is ResourceNotFound and it should have value false. This when quick watch @localizaer["Login"]. If it is true that means you don't have proper resource file. Another way to see if you are taking data from resource file is to add query param ?ui-culture=it-IT.

Comment: The `Localizer` is empty, should be a localization problem for the `.resx` files? Is unclear for me how the app can locate them

Comment: Ok I was able to fix that, seems that Visual Studio sometimes get stuck, so I restarted VS and then removed all the resx files, created new one and all works

Answer (score 0):

Open up the resx file in design mode (just double click the file) and set the access modifier to public as the following  -

[image]

I have found this following article a great help when working with localisation -

http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/

Comment: That article is from 2011 and covers ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Core, so I am not actually convinced that this would work in ASP.NET Core. Can you confirm that this works there?

Comment: Also I already tried this solution and didn't worked, the problem now is that the `@Localizer` is even empty